# How to import source code of liferay 6.2 portlet?

Tags: java, eclipse, liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I've download a few portlets from Liferay MarketPlace.

I do not know how to import them into Eclipse.

The folder with portlet contains:

```
.settings
docroot
.classpath
.project
build
```

I want to import it in a way which allows me to build it as a gradle project and deploy it on a server ( in a .jar or .war file I guess ).

Eclipse allows me to import it in this way only - Import as an existing project into workspace.

Comment: Hard to say, because (based on the provider of your MarketStore Portlet) there might be a not a common build approach to mention here. As there is a build folder in your listing, it might be a ANT Plugin SDK based project. So you can try to install a PluginSDK, put your source Projekt to the sdk/portlets folder and run the ANT build.xml in build folder. I am not that familiar with gradle, maybe there is a wrapper to call your ANT target. Which Marketplace Portlet is mentioned here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Liferay-developer-studio or download Liferay IDE from eclipse marketplace. That should give you a whole lot of options when you are doing an eclipse import.